# Open new form by passing variable after saving data into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form used to update data in database. I am updating  the data on submit button click and it is working fine .now I want to open a new form by passing few variable to new form after the updating of data into data base .In short i want the button to perform two task on single click 1.Save the data into data base 2.Open new form by passing few variable .My code is

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
$stationerytype=$_POST['stationerytype'];
$balance =$total;
$sql="update tblstationerytype set balance=:balance where stationerytype=:stationerytype";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':balance',$balance,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':stationerytype',$stationerytype[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

$_SESSION['msg']="Stationery Added successfully";
echo "<script>window.opener.location.reload();window.close();</script>";
header(viewrequest.php?uin=<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>);
```

HTML code

```
<form role="form" method="post"  class="form-inline">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn pull-right" style="margin-left:375px; margin-bottom:30px;">
</form>
```

Comment: What few variable you are talking about?

Comment: @dqureshiumar like this viewrequest.php?uin=<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>

Comment: `header("Location: viewrequest.php?uin=" . htmlentities($result->uin);` will this work for you?

Comment: yes now working but echo "<script>window.opener.location.reload();window.close();</script>"; not working now

Comment: there is no need for that line

Comment: header("Location: viewrequest.php?uin=" . htmlentities($result->uin); how to add one more variable in this ?

Comment: @nbk i want to refresh that page

Comment: header will send the you to the referenced html page amd spo there is no need to refesh the webpage.

Comment: @dqureshiumar You should **not** use `htmlentities` for URL escaping. That's what [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is for.

Comment: There's some fundamental PHP syntax errors here that mean this script has no hope of running. Do you have a good PHP introduction resource? I'd suggest starting with [PHP the Right Way](https://phptherightway.com).

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple action with single button of a html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731076/multiple-action-with-single-button-of-a-html-form)